# Jboss CLI Command to list the last file in a directory

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, jython

I need the Jboss CLI command to list the last file of a directory. For eg, I have the directory contains two files 
helloworld.sh
helloworld1.sh 
I Want a command to list only the last file.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss CLI doesn't support listing files itself AFAIK.

Nevertheless, it seems you use the Jython, so you could use its own way to do what you need. Something like:

```py
import os
os.listdir("/path/to/folder")[-1]
```